# Java link extracting Jsoup

Tags: java, html, css, web

I am parsing a web page: http://www.dn.se/nyhetsdygnet/ , at the bottom of each list of news there is a button to load more news article. When I press it the URL is changed to something like this http://www.dn.se/nyhetsdygnet/#getMoreArticles/2016-05-09/80 , and it loads more links(articles) in the list, my problem is that I have the code below, even if I give it the new link(with loaded more links) it doesnt recognize the newly loaded links , it prints only the ones that were available before pressing the load more button, here is my code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.dn.se/nyhetsdygnet/#getMoreArticles/2016-05-09/120").timeout(100000).userAgent(" Mozilla//5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit//537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome//49.0.2623.110 Safari//537.36").get();;
       Elements s = doc.select("#container-20160509 > ul > li a");


       for(Element e : s)
       {
           System.out.println(e);
       }
```

Comment: I don't know why or how the website uses the "/40", "/120", etc in the Url, but I just pasted both  http://www.dn.se/nyhetsdygnet and   ttp://www.dn.se/nyhetsdygnet/#getMoreArticles/2016-05-09/120 into two browser tabs and got exactly the same page (i.e. same list of items) in both.        That being so, unfortunately that's all any library will give you.  EDIT:  Ooops no - apologies - I was fooled by just looking at the last "12 May" list .

Comment: aha no worries, the thing is that jsoup or my code doesnt recognise the newly loaded links :/

Comment: I strongly suspect the page loads the basic number of links initially (so that's what your code gets), then kicks off some javascript that checks the url, and then uses ajax to load the extra.  Haven't been able to confirm that suspicion yet, though.

Comment: I did "curl http://www.dn.se/nyhetsdygnet/#getMoreArticles/2016-05-09/40 > x40", and /80 and /120 all returned exactly the same file.  I don't think Jsoup is the problem.

Comment: yes its the same with me thats the problem i am trying to figure out :///